# Scalatest Generator-driven property checks compilation error in Eclipse. Ok in SBT.

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scalatest, scala-ide, scalacheck

I am trying to do property-based testing using ScalaTest. I have written a few test cases using 2 custom generators and they work fine. However, the moment I define a forAll with one custom generator, such as below:

```
  it should "generate a given number of weights whose total is less than the given total when the given number is > 0, with default upperBound, lowerBound and total" in {
    // TODO: Find out why single parameter does not work. maxSize here is a workaround
    forAll(reasonableSizes) { (size: Int) =>
      whenever(size > 0) {
        val range = random.nextLong.abs
        val values = DataGenerator.generatePartialWeights(size)
        values should have length size
        every(values) should (be >= BigDecimal(0) and be <= BigDecimal(1))
        values.sum should be < BigDecimal(1)
      }
    }
  }
```

I got compilation error in Eclipse as follows:

> type mismatch;  found   : (org.scalacheck.Gen[A],
>   DataGeneratorTest.this.PropertyCheckConfigParam*)  required: ?0C[?0E]
>   Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are
>   ambiguous:  both method ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](self:
>   A)ArrowAssoc[A]  and method Ensuring in object Predef of type
>   [A](self: A)Ensuring[A]  are possible conversion functions from
>   (org.scalacheck.Gen[A],
>   DataGeneratorTest.this.PropertyCheckConfigParam*) to ?0C[?0E]

I tried the example in ScalaTest documentaiton: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/generator_driven_property_checks

by doing

```
  it should "testing" in {
    val evenInts = for (n <- Gen.choose(-1000, 1000)) yield 2 * n
    forAll(evenInts) { (n) => n % 2 should equal(0) }
  }
```

and got the same error.

However, when I compile it in SBT, there is no error.

> sbt compile 
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server
>   [info] Loading project definition from C:\xxx [info] Set current project to cree (in build file:/C:/xxx)
>   [info] Compiling 20 Scala sources to
>   C:\xxx\target\scala-2.11\classes...
>
> [success] Total time: 37 s, completed 26-Mar-2015 20:04:15

I am not sure what is wrong. Can someone help? Thanks.

Environment:

- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64-bit
- Scala IDE: 4.0.0
- Scala Version: 2.11.6
- ScalaTest Version: 2.2.4
- ScalaCheck Version: 1.12.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you perhaps post the full test class?

I ran into the exact same issue and found that there was a conflict with using the `Inspectors` trait along side the `PropertyChecks` trait. After removing the `Inspectors` trait from my test class, everything worked fine.

```scala
abstract class UnitSpec extends FunSpec
  with Matchers
  with OptionValues
  with Inside
  // with Inspectors     <= this conflicts with PropertyChecks trait
  with PropertyChecks
  with ValidationMatchers
  with MockFactory
```

Comment: You are right... Both Inspectors and PropertyChecks implements forAll so the forAll from Inspectors is taken in my case. Now - is there a way to specify which method to use in this case? If we import two classes that have the same method, we can give alias, but I am not sure what can be done for traits.